# php/mysql remove part of string and echo

Tags: php

I've got a simple set of strings:

ABC_DEF

ABC_1_DEF

I'm trying to remove the 1_ from the second string. Sometimes the 1 may be a character A-Z0-9. Any suggestions or assistance?

Comment: explode on underscore, if you have 3 parts remove the middle one, if only 2 carry on

Comment: I'm guessing this has nothing to do with MySQL so I'm removing that tag.

Comment: `preg_replace('/_._/', '_', $str)`?

Comment: Marc, simple and effective! Worked great, thanks!

Comment: If it genuinely is a MySQL question, `SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_string, '_', 1), '_', SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_string, '_', -1))`.

Comment: Matt...Having a bit of a hard time with the proper way to add that to a query...an example of my query is below that I've been using..



$query = "SELECT `position` FROM `database_1` WHERE `position` LIKE '%ABC%' GROUP BY `position` ORDER BY `position` DESC";

Answer (score 0):

Something like that for php:

```
function sup($string){
   $string = explode("_", $string);

   return count($string) > 2 ? $string[0]."_".$string[2] : $string;
}
```

Or

```
function sup($string){ 
   return preg_replace("/_.+_/", "_", $string);
}
```